# What causes Remote Desktop to pause/freeze temporarily after being minimized?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I often work between multiple windows when using Remote Desktop and when I maximize a previously minimized window it appears to freeze for a time and need to reconnect. Sometimes is turns out to be faster to re-open a fresh connection which will disconnect the previous one.

I seem to remember RDP saves bandwidth by not streaming the window when minimized. I think this may be related.

I am wondering how I might be able to avoid the freezing issue.